# Calling an MVC controller action to return a view into a Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, wordpress, rest

A bit stumped... sorry if this is vague.

I have an MVC website. I wish to create a controller action that returns a value in JSON, which I can do.

For example, my MVC website will return today's weather as a string ("Today is sunny").

I wish to call this from a Wordpress website, which is where I'm stumped.

Should I modify the JSON action to create a html view, then use an iframe in the Wordpress site to show the view?

I'd rather find a way to use javascript in the wordpress website to retrieve the value as a string and insert it into the page.

How would I go about that!?

Comment: have a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should proceed as follows:

1. From your wordpress page, make a JS ajax request to your service (MVC website)

   $.get(url, function(aJsonString){
      ....
   })
2. Retrieve the JSON data and convert it to a JS Object:

   $.get(url, function(aJsonString){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( aJsonString );
    })
3. Manipulate your DOM to show the data contained in your JS Object

   $.get(url, function(aJsonString){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( aJsonString );
      $('#result').html(obj.message);
    })

This can all be done with JQuery or more sophisticated libraries like Angular JS. Samples provided are in JQuery and code has not actually been tested.